# Longer search time for shorter index in lucene

Tags: lucene, information-retrieval

I was experimenting with Lucene on the [Cystic Fybrosis collection](http://people.ischool.berkeley.edu/~hearst/irbook/cfc.html). I made 4 indexes (seperate indexes),where one index had only `title`, while other had `abstract` and another `subject`. the last one had `all fields`.

Now I find that the search time for index which uses only title is significantly larger than for other 3 indexes. This seems counter-intuitive as the index size is small, when compared to other indices. What can be the probable reason for this?

Here is the code I have used for the benchmark

```
public class PrecisionRecall {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {

File topicsFile = new File("C:/Users/Raden/Documents/lucene/LuceneHibernate/LIA/lia2e/src/lia/benchmark/topics.txt");
File qrelsFile = new File("C:/Users/Raden/Documents/lucene/LuceneHibernate/LIA/lia2e/src/lia/benchmark/qrels.txt");
Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(new File("C:/Users/Raden/Documents/myindex"));
Searcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(dir, true);

String docNameField = "filename"; 

PrintWriter logger = new PrintWriter(System.out, true); 

TrecTopicsReader qReader = new TrecTopicsReader();   //#1
QualityQuery qqs[] = qReader.readQueries(            //#1
    new BufferedReader(new FileReader(topicsFile))); //#1

Judge judge = new TrecJudge(new BufferedReader(      //#2
    new FileReader(qrelsFile)));                     //#2

judge.validateData(qqs, logger);                     //#3

QualityQueryParser qqParser = new SimpleQQParser("title", "contents");  //#4

QualityBenchmark qrun = new QualityBenchmark(qqs, qqParser, searcher, docNameField);
SubmissionReport submitLog = null;
QualityStats stats[] = qrun.execute(judge,           //#5
        submitLog, logger);

QualityStats avg = QualityStats.average(stats);      //#6
avg.log("SUMMARY",2,logger, "  ");
dir.close();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The response time of a query does not depend on index size. It depends on the number of hits and the number of terms in the query.

This is because you don't have to read all the index data. You only need to read the document list for the query terms.